# Unity 5 does not create new scene

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm newbie to Unity 5 and I have problem with creating new scenes.  After creating a project ,I go to `File->New Scene` but the scene does not appear at all so I can't do anything with it ! Here's the image from what I see in Unity:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hit Layout in the top right corner, select "2 by 3"

You will see your scene and game view quickly that way.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Your new scene is there. Your layout is likely messed up.

[image]

Click on the **Default** in the image above(where red arrow points to) then click **Default**. It should **reset** everything to normal. You can press **Control + S** to actually save the scene.

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled the scene view and switched to it?
Maybe you are viewing the game view. There is nothing in the scene so nothing will be displayed in game view.